# Как правильно настроить 404 ошибку?

Tags: http-status-code-404

Не могу правильно настроить 404 ошибку.
Урлы строятся следующим образом:

```
part.php?mark=bmw&mod=5-seria&id=1227
```

Сейчас стоит такая проверка:

```
DBConnect();
$res=mysql_query('select * FROM '.$carBrand.' where id='.(int)$_GET['id']);
if($data=mysql_fetch_row($res))
{
}else{
      header ("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
      header('Location:./404.php');
      exit(); 
}
```

То есть идет проверка на id. И она работает. Если дописать в id несуществующую цифру, например, `id=1227343`, то срабатывает 404 ошибка.

Но если в урл `part.php?mark=bmw&mod=5-seria&id=1227` подставить еще несуществующие параметры, например:

```
part.php?mark=bmw&mod=5-seria&id=1227&nesushestvuyshiikjlkjl
```

то редиректа на 404 ошибку не происходит.

Как настроить, чтобы при добавлении любых несуществующих параметров срабатывала 404 ошибка?

Comment: Вообще, по логике вещей, тебе не следует давать 404, если были переданы дополнительные параметры.  
Тем не менее, чтобы сделать то, что ты хочешь, тебе необходимо завести whitelist-список параметров и перед обработкой строго проверять, что указаны все и только все параметры из списка.

Comment: Если переданы дополнительные параметры, значит добавляется что-то в урл. А это значит - дубль страницы.